# Bash - how to add newlines to string in loop with command substitution?

Tags: bash

I have a for loop thats iterating over a list of items, gathering statistics. The constructed string is then being sent as the body of an email using the mail command. My question is: what is the proper way to output newlines, as opposed to escaped \n characters as my script is currently doing?

Here's the relavent bash code:

```
for x in $([..]); do
    BODY="${BODY}\nReport for ${x}: \nSuccess: `get_logs $x 1`\nAttempts: `get_logs $x`"
done;
```

Comment: You can try `echo -e`

Comment: @dex'ter add this as an answer because it worked. You and socowi can battle for upvotes :D

Comment: done. I've added an answer with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can use:

```
echo -e
```

The -e flag enables the interpretation of backslash escapes

Answer (score 0):

You can use newlines inside quoted strings, the only downside of this is that you cannot indent the new lines, because the indent will be part of the string.

```
for x in $([..]); do
    BODY="${BODY}
Report for ${x}: 
Success: $(get_logs $x 1)
Attempts: $(get_logs $x)"
done;
```

Alternatively, append each line separately to make your code more readable.

```
for x in $([..]); do
    BODY+="Report for ${x}:"$'\n'
    BODY+="Success: $(get_logs $x 1)"$'\n'
    BODY+="Attempts: $(get_logs $x)"$'\n'
done;
```

`$'\n'` is an ANSI C string and will be replaced by a line feed.